# Breaking from a recursive function and returning a value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have written a javascript function like this . But I want when a cretain condition meet the function will not execute means it will break and return a true false like status.My code is like this

```
 var ActionAttributes = function (data)
    {
        var status = true;
        var attrKey = data.AttributeKey();
        //Condition to exit
        if (attrKey==''||attrKey==null)
        {
            status = false;
            return false;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Children().length; i++)
        {
            var childData = data.Children()[i];
            ActionAttributes(childData);
        }
        return status;
    }
```

Comment: nope, read it several times now, don't get what your asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: `return ActionAttributes(childData);`, You need break condition in the statement `ActionAttributes(childData)`

Answer (score 3):

You need break condition in the `for` loop. You are just invoking it, handle the returned `status`.

```
var ActionAttributes = function(data) {
    var status = true;
    var attrKey = data.AttributeKey();
    //Condition to exit
    if (attrKey == '' || attrKey == null) {
        status = false;
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < data.Children().length; i++) {
        var childData = data.Children()[i];

        //You need to break loop here
        //Add appropriate condition here
        if (ActionAttributes(childData) == false) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, that recursion is not very useful to begin with.

you call a recursion of ActionAttributes inside the loop, but never handle the returned status. So the first caller will always receive true unless the exit condition meets on the first object.

you shoul store the return from ActionAttributes into status, and then break out of the loop as soon as it's false.